# discord.js v14: how to see the number of pending messages in shards

Tags: discord.js, sharding

I'm trying to create a system to inform shard information, but I tried everything I could to make this pending message appear, and it didn't work

```
bot.shard.broadcastEval((shard) => {
 const pendingMessages = shard.pendingGuilds;
 console.log(`Shard ${shard.id} -${pendingMessages}`);
});
```

Shard 0 - undefined

Comment: What are "pending messages" ?